Distance calculation from point of origin to Destination
I am trying to calculate the distance covered by trucks (4 in number) in km from point of origin to destination. However, i tried some function with distanceTo and GetDistance but that can only easure the distance between given latitude and longitude. Although i am interested in the real time distance covered by each truck.
The movement of trucks are defined in a statechart where the charging logic is also explained
I cannot determine the distance covered by exisiting collections becasue in some transitions they are nulfied
I tried some buildin function to cover the distance.
i am looking for determining the real time distance covered by each truck.

There is no one solution.
The simplest typically is to compute the specific distance driven with each moveTo call (via distanceTo just before starting the move) and store it locally.
You can also toggle the default model logging, it tracks total agent distance covered (but you loose control of what you are measuring, beware!)
Since 8.9.0, there is also the getDistanceTravelled() function which should track what you need (I never used it so check the API)
